# Object literal expression not parsed as such when curly bracket begins on next line

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I attempted to define the following:

```
function twelveHourTime(date)
{
    let hour = date.getHours() % 12;
    if (hour == 0)
        hour = 12;
    return
    {
        hour: hour.toString(),
        minute: date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
        suffix: date.getHours() < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"
    };
}
```

and the object literal in the `return` statement was not parsed as such.

However, the following `return` statement works as it should:

```
return {
    hour: hour.toString(),
    minute: date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    suffix: date.getHours() < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"
};
```

I'm assuming that the parser treats the initial curly bracket in the former case as the start of a block rather than an object literal, but if so, shouldn't it do the same in the latter case?

Comment: The rules for automatic semicolon insertion explicitly call out the `return` case as a place where it happens. In the case where it doesn't work, it's because JavaScript assumes you meant to put a semicolon after the `return` (before the `{` on the next line).

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that. I wish they'd either made semicolons mandatory or made whitespace significant. Then there would be no need for automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: In my option `{` should always be on the same line as the current statement when writing JavaScript. Not just for this instance, but also for `function`, `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, etc.

Comment: @IsaacSaffold - Word. The halfway house of ASI is just not a good thing. And I think this specific problem is one of the big reasons [the Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style) is not popular in the JavaScript world.